# Перевод hex в код символа

Tags: java

У меня есть переменная типа `String`, в которой лежит следующее значение: `"0xF9"`.
Как мне получить выходной символ, код которого равен hex значению в этой строке?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ideone.com/6R6Igj

```
System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt("0xF9".substring(2), 16));
```

Answer (score 7):

Вариант с использованием метода [Integer.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)):

```
String str = "0xF9";
int code = Integer.decode(str);
char c = (char)code;
```

И вывод на экран в одну строку в рамках, условно говоря, code golf:

```
System.out.println((char)(int)Integer.decode("0xF9"));
```

Comment: А зачем `(int)`?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что метод `decode` возвращает `Integer`, а его к `char` привести нельзя.

Comment: Неожиданно. Зачем они его так?

Comment: @Qwertiy судя по коду, `decode` возвращает `Integer` потому, что `Integer.valueOf`, который активно используется в `decode`, возвращает `Integer`, а для `valueOf` это нормально. Видимо, поэтому и порешили оставить возвращаемым `Integer`.